# Boto/Python script on Windows does not give an error when trying to create Duplicate S3 bucket

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using a Windows machine to execute a `boto` script. I have a `boto` script file that creates a bucket. The script runs the first time and all subsequent times.

My thought is that the script should **ERROR** out the **SECOND** time because it is trying to create a **DUPLICATE** bucket – But it does not error out.

Is there a way I can have an error thrown (other than writing a script to check for bucket existence?)

**MyScript.py**

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3(profile_name='myprofile')
bucket = s3.create_bucket("myownuniquebucketname")
```

**boto.config**

```
[Boto]

debug = 2
```

Comment: If Amazon S3 silently ignores duplicate bucket creation requests, I don't think you are going to get around checking for bucket existence.  The good news is that there should be a boto api call to do just that.

Comment: Yes there is an API call to check for bucket existence, I was assuming that adding a duplicate bucket should not be allowed implicitly, obviously that does not seem to be the case. I also validated the API shows a similar behavior if you use CLI, so it seems to be a core behavior. Thanks

Comment: I would go ahead and list what you discovered as a self-answer here.  It is a little easier on the eyes than searching through comments for the answer (for future readers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `create_bucket` call is **idempotent** which is typical of REST interfaces. I have changed the code to create the bucket only if it does not exist.

```
# Boto 2.x
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3(profile_name='myprofile')

lookupResult = s3.lookup('myownuniquebucketname', validate=True)
if (lookupResult is None):
    bucket = s3.create_bucket("myownuniquebucketname")
    print("Code to create bucket")
else:
    print("Bucket already exists")
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 would not raise error for bucket creation if you try to create duplicate bucket under region us-east-1.
follow [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) and error code "BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou"